# How to perform Pause and Resume inside a loop

Tags: java, android

```
public void NumberCall() {

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        list.add(new Integer(i));
    }
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    for (int count = 0; count < 4; count++) {
        int num = list.get(count);


        mHandler = new Handler();
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                int first = list.get(0);

                    if (num == first) {
                        String s = "here is the numbert,";
                        tts.speak(s, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                    }

                    if (num == 1) {

                        String s1 = "Single Number," + Integer.toString(num);
                        tts.speak(s1, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                        textpro.setText(String.valueOf(num));
                        Num1Cal();


                    }
                    if (num == 2) {


                        String s1 = "Single Number," + Integer.toString(num);
                        tts.speak(s1, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                        textpro.setText(String.valueOf(num));
                        Num2Cal();

                    }
                    if (num == 3) {
                        String s1 = "Single Number," + Integer.toString(num);
                        tts.speak(s1, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                        textpro.setText(String.valueOf(num));
                        b3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_button1);
                        b3.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                    }
                   

                    int last = list.get(list.size() - 1);
                    if (num == last) {
                        reset.setEnabled(true);
                        reset.setClickable(true);
                        reset.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_shadow_white));
                    }
                }


        }, 3000 * count);
    }
```

I need to pause above function onClick event and again resume back it on another click event.

Comment: The suspend() method of thread class puts the thread from running to waiting state. This method is used if you want to stop the thread execution and start it again when a certain event occurs. This method allows a thread to temporarily cease execution. The suspended thread can be resumed using the resume() method.

Answer (score 0):

I won't say that this answer will be the best one but it shall definitely work in my opinion. Make a boolean variable (initial value false). Within onclicklistener, change the value to true. In for loop, do this

```
for (int count = 0; count < 4; count++) {
    if(boolean_variable){
        count--;
        continue;
    }
```

This will lead to running of loop without performing the operations and without change in count variable as well. In onclicklistener, do like this:

```
boolean_variable = (boolean_variable) ? false : true;
```